# how to create database in phonegap for all platforms?

Tags: cordova

I want to create an SQL database for a phonegap application that i am developing. I want to deploy my application to seven platforms. However, the Storage phonegap api supports only three of the platforms that are supported by phonegap as mentioned in their docs http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage.

So how do i provide persistent storage in my application such that it can be deployed to all platforms supported by phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap 1.5 supports almost all platforms except an old version of Blackberry and Bada:-

http://phonegap.com/about/features

However, I believe it's also based on SQLite which is no longer part of the HTML5 spec, so whilst support is there today, there is a question mark over the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use lawnchair (http://westcoastlogic.com/lawnchair/).
It has adapters for severall persistence implementations, including indexed-db and sqllite.